# Determine Index of Highest Value in Python's NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate an array with the index of the highest max value of each row.

```
a = np.array([ [1,2,3], [6,5,4], [0,1,0] ])
maxIndexArray = getMaxIndexOnEachRow(a)
print maxIndexArray 

[[2], [0], [1]]
```

There's a np.argmax function but it doesn't appear to do what I want...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `argmax()` function *does* do what you want:

```
print a.argmax(axis=1)
array([2, 0, 1])
```

Comment: This also exists as a top level function, thus the following also works: `maxvals = np.argmax(a, axis=1)`